# Round & Square display Detection - Android Wear Service

Tags: java, android, service, wear-os

I have a small problem, I made a Watch Face which needs a different background if the watch is round or squared. Because it's a Watch Face it's A Service and has no activity and because of that no solution I found on the net worked for me.

Is there maybe a way to detect it by code or a way to deploy two Watch Faces in the same APK?

Thanks & Greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am so sorry, I found an answer that worked.

```html
@Override
public void onApplyWindowInsets(WindowInsets insets)
{
super.onApplyWindowInsets(insets);
mIsRound = insets.isRound();
mChinSize = insets.getSystemWindowInsetBottom();
}
```

So if someone is in the same need as me, just add this to your code and it will say if it's round or not.